# Escrever input button em ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
r.Write("<th colspan='3' style='text-align:center'><input id='btEmail_" + (n - 1) + "' name='btEmail_" + (n - 1) + "' runat='server' class='btn bg-brownCinc' onclick='btEmail_' type='button' value='Update' /></th>");
```

que está dentro de ciclo while que desenha um numero indeterminado de botões (5, 10 ou 15 botões). E tenho:

```
protected void btEmail_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
}
```

Quando tento clicar num dos vários botões gerados não acontece nada, ou seja a página index não é aberta. O que há de errado neste código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto neste caso é criar o elemento programaticamente, utilizando as objetos, não montar a string com o conteúdo que terá que ser renderizado.

Para criar o elemento a ser renderizado faça assim:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        // criando elemento
        Button btnEnviar = new Button();
        btnEnviar.Text = "Texto do elemento";
        btnEnviar.CssClass = "btn btn-brownCinc";
        btnEnviar.Click += AcaoAoClicarNoBotao;

        // adiciona o elemento onde deve ser exibido
        // neste caso, para exemplo, estarei adicionando em um Panel
        Panel1.Controls.Add(btnEnviar);
    }
}
```

E depois apenas crie o evento que o botão irá executar. Exemplo:

```
protected void AcaoAoClicarNoBotao(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ação que será executada
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Evento onclick do elemento button é ClientEvent, ou seja, vai procurar uma função JavaScript

O que você precisa é invocar o  método do servidor, felizmente isso pode ser feito facilmente usando o atributo OnServerClick (sem esquecer do runat=Server)

```
<input type="button" ID="Button1" runat="server" value="Cliqur Aqui" onServerClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Isso irá disparar no server o evento  **protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)**

Você pode perceber que o botão acima será renderizado como

```
<input onclick="__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$Button1','')" name="ctl00$MainContent$Button1" type="button" id="MainContent_Button1" value="Cliqur Aqui" />
```

Note que não aparece o onclick ai.

Só mais um detahe: Você não precisa de um evento para cada botão ! Use o mesmo evento para todos os botões e mude o ID de cada um.

```
<input type="button" ID="Botao_1" runat="server" value="Cliqur Aqui" onServerClick="Button1_Click" />
<input type="button" ID="Botao_2" runat="server" value="Cliqur Aqui" onServerClick="Button1_Click" />
```

No Server:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write((sender as HtmlInputButton).ID);
    }
```

Isso irá imprimir "Botao_1" ou "Botao_2" dependendo de qual foi clicado.